# Displaying the name of the Month in Php from a data that comes from MySQL

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP(5.x) and MySQL ,

I am getting some information from MySQL in my PhP app. Which includes  Dates.

I have a full date like  01.01.2016 09:30 . How can I show this in my View(HTML) Table as `January 2016` ?

I am displaying it now like that

```
       foreach($data as $d) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='white-space: nowrap'>".$d["DatumVon"]."h</td>";
            echo "<td style='white-space: nowrap'>".$d["DatumBis"]."h</td>";
            echo "<td>".$d["dauerStunden"]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
```

The date format I show is dd.mm.yyyy but the data is stored on the database as a TIMESTAMP

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php Also `01.01.2016 09:30` is not a valid date/datetime structure your DB should be using one of those formats to store dates.

Comment: MySQL DATE/DATETIME columns are not stored like this `01.01.2016 09:30` What datatype is the column storing this date

Comment: _QUESTION:_ You have `01.01` for day and month. Which one is Day and which one is Month??? **It matters**

Comment: first one is for day , second one is for month, also European style not American

Comment: Also I have time stemps in mysql like 1365061500 it will be "translated" automatically to human dates

Comment: @AtlasOkyanus check my answer below hope it would help

Answer (score 0):

You can use php date function

```
$get_date="01.01.2016 09:30";
echo date("F Y",strtotime($get_date)); //op January 2016
```

**EDIT**

If you have timestamp as you have mentioned in comment. You can directly pass that in `date` function

```
$time_stamp = "1365061500";
echo date("F Y",$time_stamp);
```

Comment: Ok, but do you know which `01` is Day and which is Month yet?

Comment: yes @RiggsFolly it must be `dd.mm.yyyy` format as in many countries it is valid format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: But in many others it is written as `mm.dd.yyyy` and as that is NOT a valid MySQL `DATE` or `DATETIME` format. My guess is OP has stored the date in a `VARCHAR()` so it could be anything. And if it is `mm.dd.yyyy` than your code will not generate the correct answer

Comment: Will you show me where `mm.dd.yyyy` is valid date. btw OP already mentioned that its on `dd.mm.yyyy` format

Comment: Yes now he has mentioned the format, and that it is a timestamp on the database. `mm.dd.yyyy` is used all the time in the USA

Comment: I think it is `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: The seperator is actually quite irrelevant, the position is what is important

Comment: separator is also imp if you will get result of "02/01/2016 09:30" it will be `1st February 2016` but for "02.01.2016 09:30" it will be `2nd January 2016` :)

Comment: Only as related to the PHP date functions. I was suggesting people clarify the information that the OP supplied before jumping into an answer as suggested in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308302/how-to-deal-with-unclear-questions-and-their-lightning-fast-fastest-gun-in-the

Comment: Specifically paragraph 4 of this answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308358/2310830

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$originalDate = "01.01.2016 09:30";
echo $newDate = date("jS F Y", strtotime($originalDate));

$originalDate = "01.01.2016 09:30";
echo $newDate = date("F Y", strtotime($originalDate));

?>
```

Output : 1st January 2016
Output : January 2016

Comment: Ok, but do you know which `01` is Day and which is Month yet?

Answer (score 0):

strtotime : function an English textual datetime into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

getdate : Retourne la date and heure from date

You can try:

```
$date = getdate(strtotime($d["DatumVon"]));
$monthYearDate = $date["month"]."&nbsp;".$date["year"];
```

Comment: Ok, but do you know which `01` is Day and which is Month yet?